# Trigger on change on dynamic value set for react-admin SelectInput field

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Can we trigger on change of SelectInput/TextField. For example if we set value for SelectInput field using source property like:

```
<SelectInput source='domain' onChange={() => {
  //... fetch geo list
  //... then set geo value
}}/>
```

then in the same form I want to update 2nd Select input field based on first select input value like:

```
<SelectInput source='geo' .../>
```

but if I update source value of 'domain' dynamically then it is not triggering on change. Is there any way to make this possible.

Comment: Add a more complete code example, it's not clear what you want to do right now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it the other way around: it' not the domain that should notify the geo, it's the geo that should react to the domain change. That's the React way!

The react-admin documentation (https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs) explains that you need to use react-final-form's useFormState hook to get the current form state:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Edit, SimpleForm, SelectInput } from 'react-admin';
import { useFormState } from 'react-final-form';

const countries = ['USA', 'UK', 'France'];
const cities = {
    USA: ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Phoenix'],
    UK: ['London', 'Birmingham', 'Glasgow', 'Liverpool', 'Bristol'],
    France: ['Paris', 'Marseille', 'Lyon', 'Toulouse', 'Nice'],
};
const toChoices = items => items.map(item => ({ id: item, name: item }));

const CityInput = props => {
    const { values } = useFormState();
    return (
        <SelectInput
            choices={values.country ? toChoices(cities[values.country]) : []}
            {...props}
        />
    );
};

const OrderEdit = props => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
            <SelectInput source="country" choices={toChoices(countries)} />
            <CityInput source="cities" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);

export default OrderEdit;
```

Comment: Thanks @François Zaninotto, I really appreciate your response, but in situation where we have added async call on change event of SelectInput, then on edit page when value gets assigned to that particular SelectInput it will not execute on change hence async functionality will not executed. So how we can handle this situation.